# Can the current value determine the logic value(0 or 1)?

Tags: digital-logic

In case of parallel connection, is the statement "Depending on the current(electric current) value, logic (0 or 1) is determined." True or False? I do not understand why current cannot affect the voltage value in this case. Don't we need another assumption about the resistors having the same value in order for the statement to be false? I am confused.

This is a TF question from my logic design class. The answer provided is false because it is determined by voltage. I marked this as true because I thought current can affect the voltage therefore determine the logic value. But when I mailed my professor he said this is not true in case parallel connection. I am wondering why this is the case.

Comment: what do you mean by `current value`? .... does it mean `the most recent value`, or does it mean `the value of electric current` ? .... please clarify the question .... **do not add additional info into comments**

Comment: Many logic circuits have input impedance high enough that it becomes difficult to even measure the input current. I'm not sure what parallel circuits has to do with it.

Comment: zero or one can represent any state, you only need some way to discriminate between the two. You could develop a system to measure current an not voltage, it would be more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very clear question, but on logic ICs, it's the input voltage that determines if that input is high or low.  The IC doesn't know or care what current is flowing from the previous IC's output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe8TpU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So in the little diagram above, pressing SW2 changes the current flowing out of BUF1, but BUF2 doesn't care.

Comment: Thank you. I can see how the current is irrelevant.